# Will a generator work with a portable DJ setup?

Tags: setup

So, understanding the risks of using a 7500 watt gasoline powered electric generator ([Dirty Power](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dirty+power)), I was wondering if battery backup or power <del>cleaner</del> conditioner could mitigate the risks such that it will not destroy my equipment?  Is this feasible?

**What would be a good portable source of power if I have to do a DJ gig in a barn yard in the boonies?**

I am working with:

- 2800 watts of speaker power (2 satellites, 1 sub)
- Asus G74x Laptop (120 watts)
- Traktor s4 (50 watts)
- Kaoss Pad 3 (10 watts)
- Korg EMX-1 (24 watts)

Comment: The speaker wattage is just a clue, please make a measurement of the total load in Watts this is the key to the answer.

Comment: A 2800 watt speaker system really does not tell us the true wattage of consumption. If the amp has a plate that describes the input and output, e.g. INPUT 120 VAC 60 CPS, OUTPUT MAX 15 amps at 25 vdc or 375 watts. Speakers are usually way over rated. The idea is this, what is worst case power consumption. If you have an inline watts meter and measure while your gear is at peak load this will be the most reliable info. Other wise the plate info and the rest tends to be over rated and you will be buying a more expensive power system than you need.

Comment: I think 7500 Watt generator will likely be more power than you need, but you should add a 'power conditioner' between the generator and the load to assure clean power. Still you will need to figure out what the peak load is to determine which power conditioner you will need. E.G. a 1500 watt power conditioner can cost you $70 while a 7500 watt rating may cost you considerably more.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have direct knowledge of this, but my research indicates that a modern inverter-type generator should produce AC that is more than clean enough for your purposes.  Additionally, this type of generator tends to be quieter and more efficient than the alternatives.